# iphone nsoperation application freezes

Tags: ios, iphone, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have made a subclass of `NSOperation` called ˚ to achieve multiple movie downloads . In the `appDelegate.m` , I have made an object of `NSOperationQueue` .

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
   queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
   [queue setMaximumConcurrentOperationCount:5]
}
```

`MovieDownloadOperation` depends on a class called `Downloader` which actually downloads the movie 
and gives callback `movieCompletelyDownloadedWithUrl:` .
Then , I have made a property called `downloadState` in `MovieDownloadOperation` . It has different values like `"STARTED"` , `"DOWNLOADING"` , `"COMPLETED"` , `"ERROR"`.

MyDownloadOperation looks like

```
-(id)initWithUrl:(NSURL *)url
{

   if (self = [super init])
   {
      _downloader = [[Downloader alloc] initWithUrl:url];
      _downloadState = @"STARTED" ;
   }
}

-(void)main
{
    while(1)
    {
       if ([_downloadState isEqualToString:@"COMPLETED"])
         {
              NSLog(@"movie downloaded successfully");
              break ;
          }
    }

}

-(void)movieCompletelyDownloadedWithUrl:(NSURL *)url
{
    _downloadState = @"COMPLETED" ;
}
```

This works well for one movie , but when I try to download more than one movie , the UI freezes until the first is downloaded .  I think the the problem is the `while` loop inside the `main` method , is there a better way to check if the `_downloadState` is changed to `"COMPLETED"` ??

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear why the UI freezes with multiple operations, but not with only one download. But, your code sample provokes a couple of thoughts:

1. Concurrent Operation:

   Rather than having a `while` loop in `main`, and you'd generally would define your operation to be concurrent (i.e. return `YES` from `isConcurrent`). Then `movieCompletelyDownloadedWithUrl` would post the `isFinished` event, which would trigger the completion of the operation.

   In terms of how to make a concurrent operation, you might define properties for `executing` and `finished`:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, readwrite, getter = isFinished)  BOOL finished;
   @property (nonatomic, readwrite, getter = isExecuting) BOOL executing;
   ```

   You'd probably want to have a `strong` property for the URL and the downloader:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, strong)               NSURL *url;
   @property (nonatomic, strong)               Downloader *downloader;
   ```

   And then you might have the following code in the operation subclass:

   ```
   @synthesize finished  = _finished;
   @synthesize executing = _executing;

   - (id)init
   {
       self = [super init];

       if (self) {
           _finished  = NO;
           _executing = NO;
       }

       return self;
   }

   - (id)initWithUrl:(NSURL *)url
   {
       self = [self init];

       if (self) {
           // Note, do not start downloader here, but just save URL so that
           // when the operation starts, you have access to the URL.

           _url = url;
       }

       return self;
   }

   - (void)start
   {
       if ([self isCancelled]) {
           self.finished = YES;
           return;
       }

       self.executing = YES;

       [self main];
   }

   - (void)main
   {
       // start the download here

       self.downloader = [[Downloader alloc] initWithUrl:self.url];
   }

   - (void)completeOperation
   {
       self.executing = NO;
       self.finished  = YES;
   }

   // you haven't shown how this is called, but I'm assuming you'll fix the downloader
   // to call this instance method when it's done

   - (void)movieCompletelyDownloadedWithUrl:(NSURL *)url
   {
       [self completeOperation];
   }

   #pragma mark - NSOperation methods

   - (BOOL)isConcurrent
   {
       return YES;
   }

   - (void)setExecuting:(BOOL)executing
   {
       [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
       _executing = executing;
       [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
   }

   - (void)setFinished:(BOOL)finished
   {
       [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
       _finished = finished;
       [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
   }
   ```

   So, with these methods, you might then have `movieCompletelyDownloadedWithUrl` call `completeOperation` like above, which will ensure that `isExecuting` and `isFinished` notifications get posted. You'd also want to respond to cancellation event, too, making sure to cancel the download if the operation is canceled.

   See [Configuring Operations for Concurrent Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW8) section of the *Concurrency Programming Guide* for more details.
2. Don't initiate download until `main`:

   I don't see your `main` method initiating the download. That makes me nervous that your `Downloader` initialization method, `initWithURL`, might be initiating the download, which would be bad. You don't want downloads initiating when you create the operation, but rather you shouldn't do that until the operation starts (e.g. `start` or `main`). So, in my above example, I only have `initWithURL` save the URL, and then `main` is what starts the download.
3. Using `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods in `NSOperation`:

   As an aside, you didn't share how your operation is doing the network request. If you're using `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods, when you get rid of that `while` loop in `main`, you might have problems if you don't schedule the `NSURLConnection` in a particular run loop. For example, you might do:

   ```
   NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
   [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
   [connection start];
   ```

   If you're not using `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods, or if you've already addressed this run loop issue, then ignore this counsel, but, bottom line, when you fix the `main` method in your operation, you might expose the `NSURLConnection` issue that your old `main` might have hidden from you.
4. How does `Downloader` invoke `moveCompleteDownloadedWithUrl`?

   BTW, you're not showing how `Downloader` could possibly invoke `moveCompleteDownloadedWithUrl`. That looks suspicious, but I'm just hoping you simplified your code when you posted it. But if you're not using a protocol-delegate pattern or completion block pattern, then I'd be very nervous about how your multiple `Downloader` objects are informing the respective `MyDownloadOperation` objects that the download is done. Personally, I might be inclined to refactor these two differ classes into one, but that's a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSTimer` to check whether your download is completed or not. It'll not freezes your UI

```
NSTimer *localTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(checkDownloadStatus) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 

-(void)checkDownloadStatus
 {
     if ([_downloadState isEqualToString:@"COMPLETED"])
     {
          NSLog(@"movie downloaded successfully");
          [localTimer invalidate];
     }
 }
```